# WooCommerce : set TAX on product page

Tags: woocommerce

I'd like to set a specific Tax on each product. 
I see i can create tax classes, but i'm going to have many different taxes, one per product, on more than 300 products. 
Is it possible to set the tax % on the product page when i create it ? 
Do you know a plugin for that ?

Comment: You can set the tax class via the function set_tax_class() on a product when you save it.  Hook into the save_post hook to set the tax class. https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html

Comment: thanks for your reply @AndrewSchultz, so i need to code something custom ? or is there a plugin for that ?

Comment: I don't know of any plugins that would do that it seems like a unique case that you have.

Answer (score 0):

What want to do is to calculate Tax Based On SKU and not shipping address. 
So i need to have a field on product page where i can enter a TVA number, manually.

Do you think it's possible ?

OR an other way maybe : 
- have one taxe class 
- in the tax class add many taxes rates with all the same country code, and no zip code 
- create a field in the product page to assign the right tax rate for the product (instead of assign a class rate) 
What do you think about that ?